# Is it possible to make dependency between two files in IIB version 11.0.0.5?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

1. I have 2 files, second file should execute only after the completion of first file .
2. If second file is coming first, it should check whether first file is processed successfully or not .If so it can process second file .
3. If first file is not loaded/completed processing, then it should hold second file until first one processing and loading is complete

Tried using flow order node and file read node but it is not working.